# Expect in shell

Tags: shell, expect

I am using an expect code to scp a file to remote location. Below is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set DATE [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y_%m_%d}]
set VAR /LDAPBackup/binbak/Meta1/binbak_$DATE.tar
spawn scp $VAR netscape@AOAAPLD00051.nbcuni.ge.com:/home/netscape/scripts/file_scp
expect "Password:"
send "*$stg\r"
expect eof
exit
```

The error i am encountering is as below :-

```
spawn scp /LDAPBackup/binbak/Meta1/binbak_2015_05_03.tar netscape@AOAAPLD00051.nbcuni.ge.com:/home/netscape/scripts/file_scp
`Password: can't read "stg": no such variable while executing
"send "*$stg\r""
(file "./scp_dev" line 6)`
```

Can anyone tellme the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below can work :-

```
expect "Password:"
send "*\$stg\r"
```

Comment: Or use braces which prevent variable expansion: `send {*$stg}; send \r`. Or store it in a var: `set pass {*$stg}; send "$pass\r"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use sshpass like:

```
sshpass -p $password scp $VAR netscape@AOAAPLD00051.nbcuni.ge.com:/home/netscape/scripts/file_scp
```

Or if password is in file then:

```
sshpass -p $filename_with_password scp $VAR netscape@AOAAPLD00051.nbcuni.ge.com:/home/netscape/scripts/file_scp
```

Comment: No , this didn't work. It is taking as $password as a variable and throwing error while not finding it :-

Comment: Yes i assume that you are providing password in $stg variable?